# Why is the Android Namespace URI not accessable?

Tags: android, namespaces, uri, android-studio

i was going to commit a Project of me to Bitbucket and then I got some errors in my XML-Layout files that the URI is not registered.
I have the following URI in my XML Files: http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
they were automatically added so I didn't care. But now android studio said:

```
 URI is not registered (Settings | Project Settings | Schemas and DTDs)
```

so what should I do. Just ignore the Error or is there a way to fix this?

One example where it happens:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:orderInCategory="100"
      android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: I edited it out, but please don't swear on SO.  This is not Facebook or YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was reported at [android:issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56336)

As you can see, it occurs if you attempt to edit a layout file in the build folder.
You shouldn't edit those or create new ones there, those are generated.

Comment: I excluded now the build folder for my git upload. now everything works perfect :)